# How to add dynamic parameters/variables to templates rendered with ng-bind-html or custom directive (inside ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**EDIT:** Here is the solution sample based on the first answer. You're still welcome to offer further suggestions and fill some gaps in my knowledge (see comments).
plnkr.co/edit/mqGCaBHptlbafR0Ue17j?p=preview

**ORIGINAL POST**

Hello all Angular heads,

I’m trying to build a tool for building simple web pages from a set of predefined elements. The end user designs the layout by choosing which elements appear in which order (there would be a selection of maybe 20-30 different elements). An example layout:

```
Heading
Paragraph
Paragraph
Subheading
Barchart
Paragraph
```

…and so forth

Under the hood, there would be an array of Javascript objects:

```
var page_structure = [
{type: ”heading”, content: ”The final exam - details” },
{type: ”paragraph”, content: ”Bla bla bla bla bla…” },
{type: ”paragraph”, content: ”Bla bla bla bla bla…” }
…
{type: ”bar chart”, y: ”Grades”, colour: ”blue” }
…
];
```

The end user inputs parameters like content, variable, colour, etc, for each individual element.

THE PROBLEM

I can’t figure how to draw these elements on the page so that the dynamic parameters for each element are properly included.

Each element type (heading, paragraph, bar chart, other possible elements) has it’s own HTML template, which has to be able to dynamically display user-defined parameters. I’m thinking I need something like this:

```
var templates = {
heading: ”<h1>USER_CHOSEN_PARAMETER_HERE</h1>”,
paragraph: ”<p>USER_CHOSEN_PARAMETER_HERE</p>”
…
};
```

I’m using Angular’s ng-repeat directive to draw each element. I have tried using either ng-html-bind…

```
<div ng-repeat="x in page_structure track by $index">
   <div ng-bind-html="templates[x.type]"></div>
</div>
```

…or a custom directive, which I call mycomponent:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in page_structure track by $index">
   <div mycomponent component='x'></div>
</div>
```

Both methods work just dandy when there are no user defined parameters in templates. I can’t, however, wire up the parameters. With ng-bind-html, I have tried using an expression markup like this:

```
var templates = {
heading: ”<h1>{{x.content}}</h1>”,
paragraph: ”<p>{{x.content}}</p>”,
…
};
```

(I actually define templates in app controller constructor, so it’s $scope.templates = { bla bla } to be precise.)

This is just showing curlies and ”x.content” in the actual web page. How do I refer to a dynamically variable parameter inside ng-html-bind template, or is it even possible?

I also tried the custom directive route, defining the directive as

```
    .directive('mycomponent', function() {
        return {
                scope: { component: "=" },
                template: templates[component.type]
    }; )
```

This was even more messed up, since I actually couldn’t figure out how I should even try to refer to a dynamic parameter here inside the template. So I apologise my inability to offer a meaningful example of what I tried to do.

Any help or working examples of the methods I should use here are greatly appreciated. I’m happy to provide more details if needed (this is my first post in SO, so I’m still trying to get the jist of how to flesh out the questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude), in which you can have a funciton that check for the proper template to load based on the passed page structure.

```
<div ng-repeat="structure in page_structure">
    <div ng-include="getMyTemplate(structure)"></div>    
</div>

$scope.getMyTemplate = function(structure) {
    switch (structure.type) {
        case 'heading':
            return '/Views/Heading.html' // or id of a pre-loaded template
        case 'paragraph':
            return '/Views/Paragraph.html' // or id of a pre-loaded template
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'll give this a try and tell you how it goes. Do I have to keep every template in a different file, then? And how do I refer to, say, component.content parameter in those templates? With double curly markup?

Comment: yes, either in different files or if they are small, define the templates inside your main page(in a script tag) .. Then in each template use angular the normal way

Comment: Tried your solution, that works! I also made a plunker of the solution:
http://plnkr.co/edit/mqGCaBHptlbafR0Ue17j?p=preview

Comment: Two minor things still puzzle me.
1. How can I display content as html? (See the plunker - br tag shows as plain text, I wanna newline there, for example)
2. If I define templates inside main page, how do I refer to them in getMyTemplate?  Instead of return '/Views/Heading.html' I write something different, I guess?

Comment: 1- check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml .. 2- you need to return the Id of your pre-loaded template(check my code comment)

Comment: Thanks again! :)
I tried using ngBindHtml in the first place, but somehow I can't get references to parameters to work there, although they work with ng-include. Do I have to run through some extra hoops there? Should it work just similarly?
And by 2 I mean: I saw your code comment, which you were kind to provide. But how do I return an Id of preloaded template - what does that mean?