# AngularJS directive: template with scope value (ng-bind-html)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have such directive:

```
...
template: function(element, attrs) {
    var htmlTemplate = '<div class="start-it" ng-if="isVisible">\
          <p ng-bind-html="\'{{customDynamicText}}\' | translate"></p>\
        </div>';
    return htmlTemplate;
},
...
```

(as you can see also i'm using translate plugin)

and there i have a problem: in scope this value is changing, but it doesn't change in directive(

when i'm using attrs-params (sure, if customDynamicText is a static string - all works) - but i have a dynamic variable `customDynamicText`

How can i use this dynamic variable in `directive template` with `ng-bind-html`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does the info at this link help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634999/how-to-add-dynamic-parameters-variables-to-templates-rendered-with-ng-bind-html

Comment: @Monomeeth no, it doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply clever...
I forgot to remove some quote-chars...
So works:

```
...
<p ng-bind-html="' + attrs.customDynamicText + ' | translate"></p>\
...
```